# Lost my keystore, only have SHA1 from it

Tags: android, google-play, keystore, android-keystore

I have accidentally deleted my **keystore** file and now I can't update my apps in Google Play, I only have the SHA1 Fingerprint from it, and I want to know if there is a way to create a new keystore and insert that SHA1 code there, so I can use the keystore to manage my apps again...
Is there any way at all to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is `NO`.

If you have lost your `keystore` file then you can't update your application further more. You need to generate a new `keystore` file. For that you need to also upload your application with different package name with newly generated `keystore` certificate.