# update app on google play without keystore file

Tags: android

i lost the keystore file and i have been trying for 6 months to recover it and no way.

and i just want to change the admob ids for ads.

what if i downloaded my app and open the apk by archive manager then searched for the strings.xml and changes it then i save and i upload it to google play without needing the keystore?

is that mean something? or its just impossible

Comment: not an exact duplicate, as you don't even have the keystore file, but the result is the same.

Comment: possibly also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29843973/lost-my-keystore-only-have-sha1-from-it/29844543#29844543

Comment: possibly the best actual duplicate would be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file

Comment: or even https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459719/android-i-lost-my-android-key-store-what-should-i-do?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: i know all these into from your link, please dont make a war to prove that its duplicated, its not

Comment: not a duplicate, how so?